# Is it possible to render and/or recover half of an apparently damaged PNG file?

Tags: png, image-processing

I have a chunk of a [PNG file](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Contents.html), missing its end. An unknown amount of data from the `IDAT` chunk is missing, as well as the `IEND` chunk. I've inspected the `IHDR` and it looks completely fine, correctly showing the image size (1920x1080), bit depth (8), etc. The image is not interlaced.

I'm on Windows (but have a Linux box available). Opening it in Windows just gives a black window, no content (but also no error messages).

Is there any way to render what I have of the image? Or is the entire thing unreadable because the bottom part is missing?

The data is also noisy, but I don't expect it to cause much of a problem - the S/N ratio should be pretty high and, as I said, the `IHDR` is completely fine.

Comment: I'm on Windows (but have a Linux box available).  Opening it in Windows just gives a black window, no content (but also no error messages).

Comment: Interesting!  Tried this and got an error (first one!): `IDAT: Invalid distance too far back`.  Gonna follow this one down the rabbit hole and see if I can fix it.